# Finding the Matrix exponential of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

Let $A_n$ denote the $n\times n$ strictly upper triangular matrix given by
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} &                   & \cdots    &(-1)^n\frac{1}{n-1} \\
      & 0 & 1             & -\frac{1}{2}     &           &  \\
\vdots&   & 0             & \ddots           & \ddots    & \vdots \\
\vdots&   &               & \ddots           & \ddots    & -\frac{1}{2} \\
      &   &               &                  & \ddots    & 1 \\
    0 &\cdots&               &                  & \cdots    & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right);
$$
i.e. $A_n$ is a diagonal-constant matrix such that $[A_n]_{i,j} = (-1)^{i-j}\frac{1}{i-j}$ if $j>i$ and zero in other case.

I am stuck while trying to show that 
$$
\operatorname{exp}(A_n) = \operatorname{J}_n(1);
$$
where $\operatorname{J}_n(1)$ is the Jordan-Block of the length $n$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.

I have tried to give a proof by using induction without success. I will appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and attempts so far?

Comment: Let $U$ be the matrix $$U=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\& 0 &1\\&&0&1\\&&&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&&0&1\\&&&&&0\end{bmatrix}\ .$$ What is $\log(I+U)$?

Comment: If $A^n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the matrix exponential is only a sum of finite terms. Have you tried to calculate this sum?

Answer (score 0):

Denote $N = J_n(1) - I_n$. We have $N^n =0$.  Moreover 
\begin{eqnarray}
A_n = N - \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{N^3}{3}- \cdots +(-1)^{n-1}\frac{N^{n-1}}{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now you should check that

\begin{eqnarray} 
\exp\left( N - \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{N^3}{3}- \cdots +(-1)^{n-1}\frac{N^{n-1}}{n-1}\right) = I+ N + N^n\cdot (...)= I + N
\end{eqnarray}

Perhaps it is useful to check the last equality for small values of $n$.